React website with ASP.NET and IIS : API not working
I have found a lot of similar issues on the web but none was working for me, and I am so desperate after days so I am posting here and hope someone can help.
I have an ASP.NET server that serves a React website, and also works as an API for the website itself. The server runs on a Windows 11 PC with IIS, in C:/MyWebSite. This folder contains the ASP.NET server (.exe, .dll, etc), the IIS configuration (web.config) and the build React website (index.html, favicon.ico and assets folder).
The server succeed to show my main page, but it fails doing an API request. The API request fails as well when I call it from Postman, and gives me the error "HTTP 404.0 - Not Found" with these details :

Module IIS Web Core
Notification : MapRequestHandler
Handler : StaticFile
Error code : 0x80070002

FYI, the request is GET http://localhost:5058/api/configuration/settings
Concerning ASP.NET, here is my Program.cs :
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;

// Create the web application builder
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// JWT authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    string? tKey = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"];

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = tKey != null ? new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tKey)) : null
    };
});

// Add the controllers to the application (for input http requests)
builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Configure CORS policy
builder.Services.AddCors(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
        builder => {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});

// Create the App
var app = builder.Build();

// Applies the CORS policy
app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");

// Serving the static files
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

// Map the routes to the controllers
app.MapControllers();

// Undefined route will lead to index.html
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

// Run the App
app.Run();

Of course, I have created some controllers, here is ConfigurationController.cs for example :
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace AspReact.Server.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/configuration")]
    public class GeneralController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("settings")]
        public ActionResult GetSettings()
        {
            return Ok(new
            {
                language = 'fr',
                theme = 0
            });
        }

        [HttpPost("settings")]
        public ActionResult SetSettings([FromQuery] string language, [FromQuery] string theme)
        {
            m_tLanguage = language;
            m_tTheme = theme;

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}

Here is my IIS configuration :
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

NB : At first I was not doing :
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />

But the API request was returning the content of index.html... If it can help.
Please note that all this is working during development with the server running in a debug console.
I would be grateful for any help! Thanks.

Asking for tutorials is off topic on this site. BTW, while there are many good tutorials over the internet, the steps you applied were wrong. Putting everything in that flat way and with only React related rewrite rules, it won’t work out. You should go back to search engines and dig further.

I am not asking for tutorials at all. I am posting all my code, that I expect to work. Am I doing things the wrong way ? Yes of course, else would not be posting a question there. I have made many reserarches and I really try to understand how all this should work but I am stuck and asking for help is what I think to be the best way to move forward at this point.

Like I said, you made typical mistakes and your research somehow failed to land on the right tutorials. Any answer for it can be rather lengthy (tutorials themselves), or points to tutorials. That’s why I don’t think it fits this site very well.

This site is here for people to help each other, and I need help at this point. My biggest problem here is that my code and configuration seems good to me! It is not just the dumb application of a tutorial or template. I truly don't understand why my server returns this error and I truly think it should work. By the way many people could have the same resoning as I have and solving my problem could help other people. But I am not forcing anyone to help me.

It seems that the problem description is a bit confusing. From the code it looks like this is an ASP.NET Core WebApi project, what are you deploying on IIS? The "main page" you mentioned refer to which one's, React Website? And have you install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle package for WebApi app before and if you deploy this on IIS?

As LexLi and XudongPeng pointed out, there were many errors in my code that I have now resolved. But actually the problem was with the .NET Core Hosting Bundle. I had installed it but with the wrong version. After reinstalling it, the API worked. And then I was able to get everything working as I wanted after a better understanding. Thanks for taking the time to help me.
